# Is the cookie hash key specific to the appid adapter?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

looking the IBM istio appid adapter for auth purposes, i could see that the adapter generates the cookie in code using a random hashkey thats created at the adapter's startup.

If i want to run multiple instances of the adapter for high availability, won't that be problematic as they don't share the cookie signing key ?

Looking at the source code what is the config.proto in `config\adapter\config.proto` used for ? What could one potentially use it for ?

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you are asking. Any links and more details?

Comment: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/appid?topic=appid-istio-adapter

Comment: https://github.com/ibm-cloud-security/app-identity-and-access-adapter

Comment: Your question is not related to the Istio adapter, but to App ID in high availability scenarios, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a common signing key for cookies is supported but undocumented.
The adapter looks for k8s secret named `appidentityandaccessadapter-cookie-sig-enc-keys` in the `istio-system` namespace

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right. At the moment adapter can only run as a single instance, as there's no cookie sharing mechanism implemented yet. This is something we intend to address in future releases.

Comment: I thought this was the case, but after digging into the code the adapter first looks into k8s secret `appidentityandaccessadapter-cookie-sig-enc-keys`